# Select rows which don't have a field specified

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following fields:

```
object_id
attr_id
string_value
```

The object_id refers to an object in another table, as does the attribute id (they are both foreign keys).

So for example I have rows like this:

```
22, 14, blah
22, 30, argh
22, 31, moo
44, 30, argh
44, 31, kaw
```

As you can see object 44, does not have attribute 14 set with a value.

What I want to do is select all objects which do not have attribute 14 defined.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You've not specified a SQL flavour/version, but your where clause should be something like... ... where attr14 is null ...

Comment: This will not work because attr14 is not a column, the column is attr_id, so you have to a get little more involved than this

Comment: Do you want to select just object_id or do you want to join columns from the object table (or whatever the table is in which object_id is the primary key)?  If you want to join columns please provide the object table schema.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT IN` in a `WHERE` clause:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where object_id not in (select object_id
                        from yourtable t2
                        where attr_id in (14))
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44ec5/8)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 3 tables for this, and  that **you don't know what `attr_id` has been missing**,

```
SELECT c.object_id
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  a.object_id, b.attr_id
        FROM    Table1 a CROSS JOIN Table2 b
    ) c LEFT JOIN tableName d
          ON c.object_id = d.object_id AND
              c.attr_id = d.attr_id
WHERE d.string_value IS NULL
```

- [**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ab57/9)

but if you want to return all columns,

```
SELECT e.*
FROM TableName e
      INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT c.object_id
  FROM 
      (
          SELECT  a.object_id, b.attr_id
          FROM    Table1 a CROSS JOIN Table2 b
      ) c LEFT JOIN tableName d
            ON c.object_id = d.object_id AND
                c.attr_id = d.attr_id
  WHERE d.string_value IS NULL
) f ON e.object_id = f.object_id
```

- [**See SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ab57/10)

Comment: @pseudocoder why unreadable? do you know what is the value of `attr_id` has been missing? This is only an assumption, and one of it is that the query doesn't know what is the missing value of `attr_id` for each `object_id`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, either that or I don't understand your genius.  Either way, bluefeet offers a simpler approach in my opinion.

Comment: @pseudocoder i respect your opinion, anyway we have different point of view. I was thinking that the OP doesn't know what `object_id` that lacks `attr_id`. Even if he mentioned about `14` but I guess it was just an example. Anyway it's up to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.*
from MyTable m
where not exists (select 1 from MyTable m2 where m2.object_id = m.object_id and m2.attr_id = 14)
```

You can also do it with a self join, e.g.:

```
select m1.*
from MyTable m1
inner join MyTable m2 on m1.object_id = m2.object_id and m2.attr_id = 14
where m2.object_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what  you mean, but for Booleans in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE attr_id <> '14'
```

Instead of `=` which means "equal" you use `<>` or `!=` which both mean "different" (The first is a bit better supported, but it's almost insignificant);